# Finding out corner PLOTS (street corner plots) on 2 or 3 roads (ArcMap GIS)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, select-by-location

[image]Finding out corner PLOTS (street corner plots) on 2 or 3 roads (ArcMap GIS)....

I want to define the corner segments on the streets, taking into account the segments that cut on two identical streets, such as a street of the same width.
Available data: plots of land by numbering - and road lines in their width